# Cannot create Sprite with Resources.Load<> in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to change my source image of UI.Image with script. You can see below that there are two versions with the former (the one commented) working but the latter not. I have tried to change the texture type from Default to Sprite (2D and UI) but it still not working. Can someone explain why?

```
//var tex = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("candy_110/candy1_green_01");
//GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, tex.width, tex.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("candy_110/candy1_green_01");
```

Update 1: Because everyone wants to make sure that Resources.Load does not return any error, I post here 2 screenshots of the asset layout and the console.
[image: Screenshot of assets layout]

[image: Screenshot of console log]

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get any error messages or warnings?

Comment: I do not see any error messages or warnings showing up.

Comment: Both work just fine for me with an `Image` component on this object, the image file in `Resources/candy_110/candy1_green_01` and set to `Sprite ("D and UI)` ... confirm again all these are fulfilled and that there are no errors in your console (might be filtering via search-bar or error message type disabled)

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the `Sprite Mode` import setting to `Single`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure `Resources.Load("candy_110/candy1_green_01")` return you `Object` not `null`

Comment: As far as I understand, this code returns null when I pass a wrong path or the asset is not a Sprite, both are not the case I mentioned above.